# My program will only display the last account I enter, is the stack not moving when I 'pop'? nasm, assembly, x86

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

```
;this program will take  person's name, DOB, and color and store in in a file
;then it will display all the account's information

;definitions
SYS_EXIT equ 1
SYS_READ equ 3
SYS_WRITE equ 4
STDIN equ 0
STDOUT equ 1

;constant variables
section .data
askNums db 'How many accounts?', 0xa, 0xD
lenAskNums equ $ - askNums
askName db 'What is your name?', 0xA, 0xD
lenAskName equ $ - askName
askDob db 'What is your date of birth?', 0xA, 0xD
lenAskDob equ $ - askDob
askColor db 'What is your your favorite color?', 0xA, 0xD
lenAskColor equ $ - askColor

;changing variables
section .bss
name resb 10
dob resb 10
color resb 10
save_counter resb 1
show_counter resb 2

;code section
section .text
    global _start
_start:

    ;ask number of accounts to add
    mov eax, SYS_WRITE
    mov ebx, STDOUT
    mov ecx, askNums
    mov edx, lenAskNums
    int 0x80

    ;store number of accounts to add
    mov eax, SYS_READ
    mov ebx, STDIN
    mov ecx, save_counter
    mov edx, 2
    int 0x80
    
    ;value of display counter (3x that of save_counter)
    mov al, 3
    mov bl, [save_counter]
    sub bl, '0'
    mul bl
    add ax, '0'
    mov [show_counter], ax


    ;loop add accounts
    _storeLoop:
        
        ;ask name
        mov eax, SYS_WRITE
        mov ebx, STDOUT
        mov ecx, askName
        mov edx, lenAskName
        int 0x80

        ;save name
        mov eax, SYS_READ
        mov ebx, STDIN
        mov ecx, name
        mov edx, 10
        int 0x80
        push ecx

        ;ask dob
        mov eax, SYS_WRITE
        mov ebx, STDOUT
        mov ecx, askDob
        mov edx, lenAskDob
        int 0x80

        ;save dob
        mov eax, SYS_READ
        mov ebx, STDIN
        mov ecx, dob
        mov edx, 10
        int 0x80
        push ecx

        ;ask color
        mov eax, SYS_WRITE
        mov edx, STDOUT
        mov ecx, askColor
        mov edx, lenAskColor
        int 0x80

        ;save color
        mov eax, SYS_READ
        mov ebx, STDIN
        mov ecx, color
        mov edx, 10
        int 0x80
        push ecx

        ;repeat until counter = 0
        dec byte [save_counter]
        mov dh, [save_counter]
        cmp dh, '0'
        jnz _storeLoop


    ;display all users
    _displayLoop:
        ;display string on top of stack
        mov eax, SYS_WRITE
        mov ebx, STDOUT
        pop ecx
        mov edx, 10
        int 0x80

        ;loop repteats until counter = 0
        dec word [show_counter]
        mov dh, [show_counter]
        cmp dh, '0'
        jnz _displayLoop

    ;exit
    mov eax, SYS_EXIT
    int 0x80
```

I included the whole program, but I think the problem is generated on the last loop (_displayLoop). It will display the information for the last user I entered (name, DOB, color) and then it will repeat that same information for all the users, which is not correct. It should display their own separate information that I enter. I'm new at assembly and  don't understand how this is possible. I thought that once I used 'pop', that data is gone, so I'm not sure how it keeps coming back.

Comment: Your loop conditions seem wrong. And you're pushing three times but popping once per iteration only. The worst problem is you are pushing and popping addresses to your buffers, but the buffers will always contain the last contents you wrote to them. (You aren't pushing the contents of the buffers.)

Comment: I see. I was confused, I I was thinking like java programming where a new variable is created with new space of memory each loop iteration, but from what I understand I'm rewriting in the same memory location during each iteration. thanks